# how to make a plot with only dots based on letters

Tags: r, plot

I have two data frames

df1 = MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWK

```
df1<- structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = "MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWK", class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

df2 = NKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIY

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = "NKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIY", class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

df1 is 24 letters and df2 is 31 letters.

I want to make a plot as large in x axis as the number of letters in df1 and y axis as large as in df2.

I want to check like this and plot dot.

> MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWK
>
> NKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIY

check each letter of df1 with its front letter from df2 , if there is a similar letter then plot a dot, if not, then nothing in this example P and P from the df1 and df2 are similar , so I have only one dot in the position of 11 in x axis and 11 in y axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: plot]

```
v1 <- strsplit(as.character(df1$V1),'')[[1L]];
v2 <- strsplit(as.character(df2$V1),'')[[1L]];
xlim <- c(0,length(v1));
ylim <- c(0,length(v2));
xticks <- seq(xlim[1L],xlim[2L],1);
yticks <- seq(ylim[1L],ylim[2L],1);
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,xlab='df1',ylab='df2',axes=F,xaxs='i',yaxs='i');
abline(v=xticks,col='lightgrey');
abline(h=yticks,col='lightgrey');
axis(1L,xticks,cex.axis=0.7);
axis(2L,yticks,las=2L,cex.axis=0.7);
i <- which(v1==v2)-1;
## Warning message:
## In v1 == v2 :
##   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
points(i,i);
```

---

If you want to require more adjacent characters to match, then you can replace the `i <- which(v1==v2)-1` line with this:

```
cmp <- v1==v2;
len <- length(cmp)-2L;
i <- which(cmp[seq(1L,len=len)]&cmp[seq(2L,len=len)]&cmp[seq(3L,len=len)]);
```

Or you can replace that last line with this, for any `N`:

```
N <- 3L; len <- length(cmp)-N+1L;
rowSums(sapply(seq_len(N),function(i) cmp[seq(i,len=len)]))==N;
```

Alternative using `Reduce()`:

```
N <- 3L; len <- length(cmp)-N+1L;
Reduce(`&`,as.data.frame(sapply(seq_len(N),function(i) cmp[seq(i,len=len)])));
```

Comment: can you please also give solution if a three letters where similar instead 1 letter ?

Comment: thanks, I liked it and accepted your answer ! thanks

Comment: I think the sapply you rowSums over could be written as `embed(cmp, N)`

Comment: @Frank The column order is effectively reversed between the two approaches, but since we end up summing over the rows, you are correct that `embed()` can be used here. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @bgoldst is it possible to make the points for each letter against all letters from the other df? I am afraid if i ask again another question, people make me negative :-D